# Variable-length argument list in C++ object

Tags: c++, oop, visual-c++

Good evening,

I'm writing some classes, and I have a case where I would like a class method to take a variable number of arguments. I had issues getting this to compile, so I set up a very simple test case:

TestObject.h:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <stdarg.h>

class TestObject
{
    public:
    void test(int intCount, ...);
};
```

and TestObject.cpp:

```
#include "TestObject.h"

void TestObject::test(int intCount, ...)
{
    va_list objList;
    va_start objStart(objList, intCount);
    int numArgs = va_arg(objList, int);
}
```

Finally, main.cpp:

```
#include<stdarg.h>

int maxof(int n_args, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, n_args);
    int max = va_arg(ap, int);
    for (int i = 2; i <= n_args; i++) {
        int a = va_arg(ap, int);
        if (a > max) max = a;
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return max;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int max = maxof(3, 1, 3, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

main.cpp will compile just fine on its own, so I've narrowed it down to the case where the variable-length argument is in a class. When I add the classes to the project and try to compile, the build fails with the error C2065: '__crt_va_start': undeclared identifier. I'm building in Visual Studio 2015.

I'm aware that C++ has variadic templates, but whenever I get into template classes, I always seem to have to convert the class and usually related classes into header-only files and I'd like to avoid that. What I would probably do alternatively is just take a vector argument of some generic type.

Can someone tell me if I'm missing something here? Should I be able to compile and run a class method that has a variable-length argument in C++, or is this just something that's not supported?

Thanks!

Comment: `va_start objStart(objList, intCount);` -> `va_start(objList, intCount);`

Comment: FWIW, there's already a `maxof` in `<algorithm>`: `std::max({1, 3, 2});`

Comment: @RSahu Ah! Silly me.. always missing the simple answer and assuming that it's something more complex. Thanks.. that works. Yeah.. the maxof thing was just a code sample I pasted in for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Using a modern compiler you should not fall back to this old-style ellipsis syntax. For your purposes [std::initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) is pretty good an alternative.
Look how simple the code with it is:

```
#include <limits>

int maxof(std::initializer_list<int> args)
{
    int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    for(auto arg : args)
        if(arg > max) max = arg;
    return max;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int max = maxof({3, 7, 1, 3, 2, 5});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Neat for this case - but I write a lot of debugging and exception classes that take a printf string and ellipsis (and hug gcc's ability to warn about incorrect arguments).